# Form submit data preview in different viewmodel

Tags: aurelia

I have a form view and viewmodel, and when I submit a form, I am redirecting to a preview viewmodel. I want to get the submitted form data in this viewmodel for user the preview what he/she input.

Comment: Are you sure you want to redirect? The nature of a "modal" view is usually that it is shown above another view. So could it be that you just want to `show` (or make it visible if you will) the modal view instead of redirecting to it?

Comment: I have a view and view-modal with name GenrateInvoice, there is form, when user submit that form it goes to GenrateInvoice view-modal. 
Then page will redirect to preview , there is i want data which user submitted. Hope it clear

Comment: Ah I see... think you mean view model. And you like to push the created object to the preview view, or at least make it available in the viewmodel of the preview. In fact state storing would help you. Easiest quick fix would be create a class and register it as a singleton in DI container (which is happening by default) and pass that data from the form to the class, and after in the preview-view grab it from there. Cleanest way would be to use aurelia store: https://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/store#introduction